# handling RenderItem in react native

Tags: react-native, render, react-native-flatlist

I would like to get help with RenderItem in React Native.
I have a list of hours which handled in this function(added a link to the code because its over 100+ lines)

h ttps://p aste.ofcode.org/P7UVHxed8NiuETZDw4hvvP (Cant add the link so i did it)

This is the RenderItem function:

```
const renderHours = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            handleClientChoose(item);
          }}
        >
          <ListItem
            bottomDivider
            containerStyle={{
              backgroundColor: "white",
              borderColor: "black",
              borderWidth: 1,
              paddingVertical: 12,
              paddingHorizontal: 25,
              borderRadius: 15,
              marginBottom: 6,
            }}
          >
            <ListItem.Title
              style={{
                fontWeight: "bold",
                color: "black",
              }}
            >
              {moment(item).format("LT")}
            </ListItem.Title>
          </ListItem>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

I have a list of hours, for example: 9:20,9:40,10:00 and etc.. when user pick an hour and the hour is handled in the database, **i want that Hour to be deleted from the list that rendered**

Cant figure out how to handle this situation, you can invite me to chat or something for further discussing

Comment: Assuming that you are using a renderItem it must be a flatList so simply update state which has the array which will cause the screen to re render

Comment: Will you mind chatting with me again?? it

Comment: Yeah sure, but chats get enabled after some discussion in normal thread, how can i help you

Comment: i want to explain myself in a better communicational way haha, maybe we can figure this out together

Comment: If a user picks and hour its automaticlly disapper from the list, but when and app reRender the hour come back again, the goal is to make this hour disappear forever

Comment: so do you get the data for each update ? or the state value is kept as it is ?

Comment: The whole process is in handleClientChoose()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222795/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-osher-revach).